# Why isn't $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ surjective in the category of Rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Why isn't $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ surjective in the category of Rings?

I have read that this inclusion is the usual counterexample of a ring epimorphism that isn't surjective, but I didn't find any proof, why it isn't surjective. Maybe the proof is so trivial, that it just isn't written down? I was thinking, that maybe the fact that $\frac12$ is not in the image set would suffice as a counter example.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: yes, I guess that $\Bbb Q \setminus \Bbb Z \ne \emptyset$ is enough to show it

Comment: Yeah, it is maybe that simple. Thanks :)

Comment: What does "surjective in the category of Rings" mean?

Comment: Yes, of course; surjective means that the image of the map covers the codomain. In this case, the formal inclusion $i:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is just $i(z):=\frac{z}1$, so the inclusion never covers any noninteger fraction (because if, say, $\frac12=\frac{z}1$, then by the construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ we would have $1=2z$, which is impossible, as 1 is odd).

Comment: I find funny that you didn't have any problem in understanding that $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is an epimorphism, but you wonder why it isn't surjective :) different people think differently!

Comment: Maybe I am not used to things that are too simple and always search for more complex proofs. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Surjective" just literally means that the underlying map of sets is surjective.  (So, this notion only makes sense in categories with a chosen "forgetful functor" to Set.)  So, as you say, since $\frac{1}{2}$ is not in the image of the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$, it is not surjective.  This is indeed usually considered obvious enough to not be spelled out explicitly.